# How to extract specific lines from a textfile and store in a list(python)

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following format:

```
356693

2013 46,  2013 67,  2013 47,  2013 63,  2013 59,  2013 76
MECN1001, MECN1003, CHEM1033, MATH1014, PHYS1014, PHYS1015

522021

2009 45,  2009 49,  2009 67,  2009 54,  2009 67,  2009 83,  2010 46,  2010 91,  2010 42,  2010 60,  2010 52,  2011 61,  2011 65,  2011 56,  2012 53,  2012 54,  2012 45,  2012 45,  2012 43,  2012 63,  2013 66,  2013 62,  2013 50,  2013 83,  2013 69,  2013 74,  2013 100
MECN1001, MECN1003, CHEM1033, MATH1014, PHYS1014, PHYS1015, MECN1001, MECN1003, MECN2011, ELEN2000, MATH2011, MECN1001, MECN2006, MECN2011, MECN2000, MECN2005, MECN2010, MECN2012, MECN2013, MECN2014, MECN2010, MECN2012, MECN2013, MECN3002, MECN3010, MECN3028, MATH3026
```

The numbers `356693` and `522021` are particular student numbers.

Now I've opened the file and read the lines in but I want to extract just the lines with the student numbers and store it in a separate list. How do I extract just the lines with student numbers?

(Bear in mind that the text file contains much more data than this, I've just taken this piece to get help)

Comment: Okay I've figued out a way to do it but I don't think its a very efficient way. My thinking was that since the numbers I want appear on every fourth line, I'll just have a count that goes through every 4th line and takes that value. Here's my code: def main():
    with open("Test.txt", "r") as textfile:
        track = 0
        Student_Numbers = []
        lines = textfile.readlines()
        while track < len(lines):
            Student_Numbers.append(lines[track])
            track = track + 4
            print(Student_Numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest going through the file line by line, and for each line check it against a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to see if it's a 6 digit number. If it is, print it out.

```
import re
student_num = re.compile("[0-9]{6}") // 6 digits
with open("data_file") as f:
    for line in f:
        if student_num.match(line.strip()):
            print line.strip()
```

Alternatively, if all of the data is in the format given above, you don't need regex, and can instead rely on line length, such as:

```
with open("data_file") as f:
    for line in f:
        if len(line.strip())==6:
            print line.strip()
```

However if there is *any* chance that the format won't be entirely consistent, I would use the regex version, as it matches more precisely.

Comment: Great, thanks! All of the data in the file is in the format given and your alternative method works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this `only` works if the number of digits is constant.

Comment: Yes, this is assuming that IDs will always be 6 numbers, however, updating it to other numbers is reasonably trivial in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file line by line, parse each line into its constituent fields, and check for the number of fields in the line. If there is only 1 field, this is the user number.

```
f = open("data_file")
for line in f:
    data = line.strip().split(',')
    if len(data) == 1:
        print data[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a loop with a couple conditions.   For example:

```
s = """356693

2013 46, 2013 67, 2013 47, 2013 63, 2013 59, 2013 76 MECN1001, MECN1003, CHEM1033, MATH1014, PHYS1014, PHYS1015

522021

2009 45, 2009 49, 2009 67, 2009 54, 2009 67, 2009 83, 2010 46, 2010 91, 2010 42, 2010 60, 2010 52, 2011 61, 2011 65, 2011 56, 2012 53, 2012 54, 2012 45, 2012 45, 2012 43, 2012 63, 2013 66, 2013 62, 2013 50, 2013 83, 2013 69, 2013 74, 2013 100 MECN1001, MECN1003, CHEM1033, MATH1014, PHYS1014, PHYS1015, MECN1001, MECN1003, MECN2011, ELEN2000, MATH2011, MECN1001, MECN2006, MECN2011, MECN2000, MECN2005, MECN2010, MECN2012, MECN2013, MECN2014, MECN2010, MECN2012, MECN2013, MECN3002, MECN3010, MECN3028, MATH3026"""

toks = s.split()

student_numbers = []

for token in toks:
    if token.isdigit() and len(token) == 6:
        print 'Student # %s' % (token)
        student_numbers.append(token)

print len(student_numbers), ' student numbers found'        

"""
--Outputs--

Student # 356693
Student # 522021
2  student numbers found
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension like this:

```
with open("data_file") as f:
    print [x.strip() for x in f if x.strip().isdigit()]
```

this strips the lines and check if the return value is a digit, it accepts it in the result list.

and the output will be:

```
['356693', '522021']
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! This also works quite well!

Comment: you're welcome, pick whatever suits you.